# RxJava Subject: Listen to different type that the one it emits

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I've been poking around with chaining Rx events and am having a bit of trouble getting what I want to work.

I'm basically requesting a user permission, requesting the user's location if it's been granted and then requesting data from an API. The code below is from a `ViewModel` and I want my `View` (technically a `Fragment`) to listen. My issue with the code below is that (obviously), my first flatmap isn't getting called as no initial event is triggering my `Subject`. I've been trying a few variants of this code but can't find the right syntax for what I'm trying to achieve.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var dataSubject = PublishSubject.create<Array<Data>>()

fun getData() : Observable<Array<Data>> {

    dataSubject
            .flatMap { permissions.request(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) }
            .flatMap { granted: Boolean ->
                if (granted) {
                    locationProvider.lastKnownLocation
                } else {
                    throw Error()
                }
            }
            .flatMap { location: Location ->
                dataRepository.getData(location.latitude, location.longitude)
            }

    return dataSubject

}
```

Comment: So, why are you using the `PublishSubject` then? you can just remove it.

Comment: Just use a `Observable.defer()` it will only subscribe to the chain once you subscribe to the `Observable`

Comment: I'm trying to keep a reference to my Observable and be able to "refresh" my data by just calling getData rather than creating a new subscription

Comment: so you need a reference to the `Subject` in order to "push" `onNext()` calls then. I recommend you use something like `.startWith(Any())` in your chain for initial call.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I've tried adding startWith(Any()) at the beginning of my chain already and it doesn't seem to be starting it and therefore doesn't start the chain

Comment: because you're returning `dataSubject` - you should return the chain i.e. return dataSubject.flatmap ...etc Obseravble are immutable, so you're chain executes only within the context of the method, but nothign is acually subscribed to it ...

Comment: Mmh I actually have the same issue returning the chain directly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160848/discussion-between-ben-and-mark-keen).